# Improving the router

Tags: php, routes

Right now, I'm trying to improve my MVC router dispatch function. My main problem is that users can attempt to access objects and if it fails, obviously, a blank page is returned.

For example, if I have an object named `error` and one of the class methods is `setType()`, a user can enter `error/settype` is the URI.

All urls are written to `index.php?url=$1`

```
$url = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

    $controller = !empty($url[0])  ? $url[0]  : 'home';
    $method = !empty($url[1]) ? $url[1] : 'index';
    $params = !empty($url[2]) ? $url[2] : $_POST;


    if (class_exists($controller)){

        $dispatchedController = new $controller;

        if (! method_exists($controller, $method)){
            /**
            * Error handling
            **/
        }

        return $dispatchedController->$method($params);

    } else{
            /**
            * Error handling
            **/
    }
```

How could I improve my router? Providing a whitelist or blacklist isn't very practical, I would think.

Comment: What you have is mostly a *dispatcher*, not a router. Seizing opportunity for shameless self-promotion: http://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router

Comment: Well done deceze...., I like it!

Comment: @deceze that specific function is called `dispatch`, there are other routing functions which I've omitted.

Comment: This question belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).